# Heating Issue — hot water baseboards

Tags: boiler, hot-water, baseboard

and thank you.

I have a gas hot water boiler, two story house, hot water baseboards on top and first floor, boiler in the basement, separate circulating pump and loop for each floor.

The boiler kicks on at a water temperature of 137 degrees 24psi and shuts off at 152 degrees 34psi.

I have the honeywell aquastat L4006 manual reset. The high limit is set at 230 deg, however I do not see a differential adjustment.

The temperature of the water does not get above 152 deg according to the boiler’s temp/pressure gage and the baseboards are supposed to operate at 270/180 degrees. There is no air in the lines. Is my aquastat the problem?

I can never get the upstairs warmer than 70 deg., and do not run the first floor heat at all (Love free AC).

How can I raise the water temperature from my boiler?

Thank you again.